# How to convert Time format in MySql to String in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, string, time

I am using hibernate to take out some records from my MySql database. The DepTime attribute in my table is of time format (hh:mm:ss). How can I convert it into string in Java? Following code is giving a type mismatch error at line 6.

```
List<?> dataList3 = DBOperation.getqpidfromAssessment(6);
if(dataList3.size()>0)
{
   for (Iterator<?> iterator = dataList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Route rt = (Route) iterator.next(); 
    String depTime=rt.getDepTime();
    double lt=rt.getLatitude();
    log.debug("Lat : "+lat);

    }
}
```

Comment: Try `rt.getDepTime().toString()`

Comment: Please give the *exact* error message. You're leaving us guessing at the moment.

Comment: @user1425223: When you have an answer you find acceptable, click in the checkmark next to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.toString()` function to convert anydata into string in java.

```
  String depTime=rt.getDepTime().toString();
```